# watchOS and cross platform cordova apps compatibility

Tags: ios, cordova, watchkit

We have a cross platform mobile app developed using phonegap/Apache Cordova which runs on iOS, Android and Windows. The app is mostly coded in javascript and we created platform specific plugins for some of functionality where ever Phonegap is inadequate. Now we want to extend the app for Apple watch. In watchOS1.x, the app running on watch is just the UI and the actual business code and the logic are still in the mobile app.  But in watchOS2.0 , it looks like the watch itself can run the app independently even though it still needs to be paired. The business code and the resources can run on the watch itself. So what are the options to extend the existing mobile app to watch ? Is there any way we can salvage good part of the business code created in javascript or do we need to recreate all that in native language again ?

Answer (score 0):

With WatchOS 1 and 2 you can use [this plugin](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/applewatch) which lets you create the UI in Javascript (although there are limitations). You can reuse the business logic in your phone app as this plugin is WatchOS 1-style, so the watch invokes the phone (even when the phone app is closed).